# Add spacing to middle column of a table

Tags: html, css, html-email, css-tables

I am trying to create an email template where I will have a grid of 3 icons being displayed. 1 rows of 3 icons.

Currently I have the following markup:

```
<table bgcolor="red" width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="outerContainer">
<tr>
   <td>
       <table bgcolor="yellow" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
           <tr>
               <td bgcolor="green" align="center">
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                ICON 1
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
               </td>
               <td bgcolor="green" align="center">
                    <table cellspacing="20" cellpadding="10" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                ICON 2
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
               </td>
               <td bgcolor="green" align="center">
                   <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                ICON 3
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
               </td>
           </tr>
       </table>
   </td> 
</tr>
```

However, I am struggling... What I'd like to do is only add spacing to the middle containers and have the outer containers touching the edges. I've been experimenting with cellspacing but each time I use it it adds spacing around all cells.

So ICON 2 would have spacing to it's left and right but the others would remain untouched. Hope this makes sense!

Can anyone advise on the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that the reason it's adding spacing around all of the cells, is because of your table width.  Without specifying widths, the table will space the columns as evenly as it can over the 600px.

I'd probably get rid of all of the padding from the inner tables for ICONS 1 and 3, and set a `width` of `1` on their `td` container.  That way, they will default to being just the size of their contents, and your middle cells will be whatever's left over.

It's a bit hacky, but daft things like this are often needed for creating emails that are consistent in email applications (thanks for that, Outlook!).

```
<table bgcolor="red" width="600" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="outerContainer">
<tr>
   <td>
       <table bgcolor="yellow" width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" border="0">
           <tr>
               <td bgcolor="green" align="center" width="1">
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                ICON 1
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
               </td>
               <td bgcolor="green" align="center">
                    <table cellspacing="20" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                ICON 2
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
               </td>
               <td bgcolor="green" align="center" width="1">
                   <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                ICON 3
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
               </td>
           </tr>
       </table>
   </td> 
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify,is this what you are trying to achieve:

[image]

Possibly just without the bottom yellow piece.

Comment: That is correct - perhaps with considerably more space between the cells, maybe 10px

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little unclear, but is this what you're trying to achieve?

Replace what you currently have for the td containing ICON 2 with this:

```html
<td style="padding: 0 100px">
    ICON 2
</td>
```

Also, remove the cellpadding & cellspacing properties you've applied within your code.

Comment: How is it unclear?.... I've said that I'd like to add spacing around the middle cell (ICON 2) but keep the others (ICON 1 and ICON 3) to the sides. In such a way that the background will show through.

Comment: "Add spacing to the middle containers..." while there's only one container, this ask was a bit unclear. I believe I translated the ask correctly, though. Does the code snippet above do what you're looking for? It matches the picture that @Rookie sent.

Answer (score 0):

Here is way of adding spacing around the inner two cells. I have added CSS to show how it looks. The middle td has a padding of 10px (left and right). This number can be increased to what you want.

```css
table table td{border-left:1px solid #ffffff;border-right:1px solid #ffffff;}
table table td table td{border:0px;}
/* the above CSS is for visual purpose only */
```

```html
<table bgcolor="red" width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="outerContainer">
<tr>
   <td>
       <table bgcolor="yellow" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
           <tr>
               <td bgcolor="green" align="center">
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                ICON 1
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
               </td>
               <td bgcolor="green" align="center" style="padding:0px 10px;">
                    <table cellspacing="20" cellpadding="10" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                ICON 2
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
               </td>
               <td bgcolor="green" align="center">
                   <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                ICON 3
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
               </td>
           </tr>
       </table>
   </td> 
</tr>
</table>
```

If this doesnt work for you, then you can add a padding side the table that is inside the middle cell.

Hope the above helps.